# Is it posible to generate dynamic forms using the FormBuilder in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

As shown here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html it is posible to generate forms dynamically with the data events.

In the example given new fields are added with a *FormFactory*, which is a little less convenient than the *FormBuilder* provided in the *buildForm* method.

There is a way to build dynamic forms in the *buildForm* method:

```
$this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $object);
```

Inside the *buildForm* method you get the object in the options array as 'data', thus provinding a way to dinamically build your form depending on the data.

This is not as powerful as the data events (request binding is an example).

Is there a way to use the data events with the *FormBuilder*? I think form building should be seamless whether you are building a static form or a dynamic one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create fields:

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
{
    $data = $form->getClientData();
    if ($data && is_array($data) && count($data)) {
        $children = $form->getChildren();
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
            $children[$k]->add($this->form_factory->createNamed('hidden', 'name', $v))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah. What mixes everything is that in some help like this, we do not kknow whether it is a ``buildView`` on the `Form` or the `*Type`.